# How Can I configure TS to not transpile in case of error?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'd like to configure my tsconfig.json file to block transpile in case of error, but I dont find this flag or configuration in docs. Someone know how Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tsconfig options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

tsoption --noEmitOnError: true